# Finding A Sporting Team Streak in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table Schedule for a local high school football conference. This is in **MySQL**. My goal is to include the "streak" for each team. If a team wins 2 games in a row the streak is W2, or if a team loses 4 games in a row, the streak would be L4.

Here's my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `Schedule` (
  `ScheduleId` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Schedule Id',
  `SportId` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Sport Id',
  `HomeTeamId` int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Home Team Id',
  `AwayTeamId` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Away Team Id',
  `StartTime` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Start Time of Event',
  `HomeTeamFinal` double default NULL COMMENT 'Final Score of Home Team',
  `AwayTeamFinal` double default NULL COMMENT 'Final Score of Away Team',
  `IsRegularSeason` bit(1) NOT NULL default b'1',
PRIMARY KEY  (`ScheduleId`)
)
```

I currently have a "Standings" query that shows the Won, Loss, Total, PF, PA, Percentage and Games Behind or each team.  However, with this, I wanted to include the streak of each team.

My Standings SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT  T.SchoolName, R.Won AS W, R.Lost AS L, R.Total AS T, R.PF, R.PA, R.GB, R.Percentage AS P
FROM Teams AS T
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  TeamId, 
                        SUM(Win) As Won, 
                        SUM(Loss) as Lost, 
                        SUM(Win+Loss) as Total,
                        PtsFor AS PF,
                        PtsAgainst AS PA,
                        CASE WHEN (SELECT SUM(Win-Loss) As WLSpan FROM WinsLosses GROUP BY TeamId Order By Win DESC LIMIT 1)-(SUM(Win)-SUM(Loss))=0 THEN '--'
                            ELSE ROUND(ABS((SELECT SUM(Win-Loss) As WLSpan FROM WinsLosses GROUP BY TeamId Order By Win DESC LIMIT 1)-(SUM(Win)-SUM(Loss)))/2,1) END GB,
                    ROUND((SUM(Win)/SUM(Win+Loss)*100),2) AS Percentage
        FROM WinsLosses AS R
        GROUP BY TeamId
        ORDER By Won DESC
) R ON T.Id = R.TeamId
ORDER BY R.PF DESC, T.SchoolName
```

And my WinsLosses view is:

```
select 
    `Schedule`.`HomeTeamId` AS `TeamId`,
    (case when (`Schedule`.`HomeTeamFinal` > `Schedule`.`AwayTeamFinal`) then 1 else 0 end) AS `Win`,
    (case when (`Schedule`.`HomeTeamFinal` < `Schedule`.`AwayTeamFinal`) then 1 else 0 end) AS `Loss`,
    `Schedule`.`HomeTeamFinal` AS `PtsFor`,
    `Schedule`.`AwayTeamFinal` AS `PtsAgainst` 
from `Schedule` 
where ((`Schedule`.`HomeTeamFinal` != '0') and (`Schedule`.`AwayTeamFinal` != '0')) 

union all 

select 
    `Schedule`.`AwayTeamId` AS `TeamId`,
    (case when (`Schedule`.`AwayTeamFinal` > `Schedule`.`HomeTeamFinal`) then 1 else 0 end) AS `Win`,
    (case when (`Schedule`.`AwayTeamFinal` < `Schedule`.`HomeTeamFinal`) then 1 else 0 end) AS `Loss`,
    `Schedule`.`AwayTeamFinal` AS `PtsFor`,
    `Schedule`.`HomeTeamFinal` AS `PtsAgainst` 
from `Schedule` 
where ((`Schedule`.`AwayTeamFinal` != '0') and (`Schedule`.`HomeTeamFinal` != '0'))
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a couple days and am stuck.  How would you best go about doing a streak with this database schema.

Comment: If the sequence is W,W,W,L,W,W -- Is that a W3 (the longest), or W2 (leading up to 'now')?

Comment: Would be great if you included a data sample and the expected result for it.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually figured this out in Postgres and then translated, my apologies if I missed a bit of syntax.  This will show the win/loss streak for every game.  I did not take different sportids into account here.

```
create table `winloss`
(
    `counter` int(10) auto_increment,
    `teamid` int(10),
    `starttime` datetime,
    `iswin` int(10),
    `winstreak` int(10),
    `losestreak` int(10)
);

--enter all teams in a single row with if they won or lost, order by teamid and gametime
insert into winloss (teamid, starttime, iswin)
select hometeamid teamid, starttime, case when hometeamfinal>awayteamfinal 
then 1 else 0 end iswin
from Schedule s
union all
select awayteamid teamid, starttime, case when hometeamfinal<awayteamfinal 
then 1 else 0 end iswin
from Schedule s
order by teamid, starttime;

DECLARE wonlost_counter int;
DECLARE wonlost_teamid int;

DECLARE prevwonlost_counter int;
DECLARE prevwonlost_iswin int;
DECLARE prevwonlost_winstreak int;
DECLARE prevwonlost_losestreak int;

DECLARE i int := 1;
DECLARE endi int;

--how many are in the table
SELECT endi=MAX(counter) FROM winloss;

--at each row, determine if this win/loss is a streak and add on
WHILE (i <= endi) DO
    SELECT wonlost_counter=counter, wonlost_teamid=teamid FROM winloss WHERE counter=i;

    select prevwonlost_counter=counter, prevwonlost_iswin=iswin, 
        prevwonlost_winstreak=winstreak, prevwonlost_losestreak=losestreak
    from winloss where counter = wonlost_counter-1 and teamid=wonlost_teamid;

    UPDATE winloss
    SET winstreak=
        CASE WHEN iswin=1 and prevwonlost_counter is not null and prevwonlost_iswin=1 then prevwonlost_winstreak+1
            when iswin=1 and prevwonlost_counter is not null and prevwonlost_iswin=0 then 1
            when iswin=0 then 0
            else 1
            end,
        losestreak= 
        CASE WHEN iswin=0 and prevwonlost_counter is not null and prevwonlost_iswin=0 then prevwonlost_losestreak+1
            when iswin=0 and prevwonlost_counter is not null and prevwonlost_iswin=1 then 1
            when iswin=1 then 0
            else 1
            end
    WHERE counter = wonlost_counter;

    i := i + 1;

END WHILE;

select * from winloss;
```